# Feature Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

In statistics we hardly ever do feature normalization. We center covariates when needed, but don't do normalization. In machine learning, specifically deep learning feature normalization is paramount. Why is it important in some application, but not important in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the machine learning approaches scaling is important because it will influence the computation of the objective function.

For example, many algorithms use Euclidean distance to do classification, if you have a feature that has values much bigger than the other features, it will dominate the distance and thus the predictions you get will be only influenced by this sole feature.

Scaling also helps gradient descend (method used in many algorithms to minimize the error function) converge much faster. SVMs also train faster with normalized values.

In summary, having all values on the same scale helps with the computation. My guess to why it is so important on machine learning and not so necessary on statistics is that machine learning algorithms usually have loops that iterate many times. At each iteration the values "out of scale" influence more and more, dominating the model. On the other hand statistic methods don't have these loops, so the scaling doesn't affect it as much.